# How to solve Operand type clash: varbinary(max) is incompatible with text

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

I'm trying to insert documents to a table in a DB, but I continue to get this error:

> **Operand type clash: varbinary (max) is incompatible with text**

any direction would be extremely helpful.

The Document table has many columns, I only picked these two thinking I don't need all 50 columns which majority of them are null; both columns are set as (text, null) as the majority of the columns all (text, null).

I am hoping that I don't need to change anything to the database and that there is a way to change the code so that the files can populate correctly to the Documents table.

Here is my HttpPost:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void UploadFiles()
    {
        if (!(Request.Files?.Count > 0)) return;
        var filesCount = Request.Files.Count;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file?.FileName);
                if (fileName != null)
                {

                    var fileBytes = new byte[file.InputStream.Length];
                    file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                    file.InputStream.Close();

                    var cmdStr = "insert into [dbo].[Documents] 
                    (DocumentName, DocumentLink) values(@val,@filename)";
                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(con))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, connection);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", fileBytes);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", fileName);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to store a byte array in a `text` column? Like the error message suggests, binary data is supposed to be stored in a `varbinary`. If you know the file is a text file, read it into a `string` and store that.

Comment: Why are you even using the text datatype? It has been deprecated for almost 15 years now in favor of varchar(max). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @SeanLange or nvarchar(max) if you want Unicode support

Comment: Do you have your parameters backwards?  Seems like the `fileName` would go into `DocumentName` and maybe the file data into `DocumentLink`?

Comment: @Steve nvarchar(max) is the replacement for ntext. I didn't mention it because the OP is using text. :)

Comment: @GSerg thanks for responding, what would you suggest? I am not able to change the text column in the db, but I would like to read it into a string, it sounds like the direction I should take.  can you share an example?

The DocumentName column holds files ie .xls, .msg, .tif, .pdf and DocumentLink is basically a file that is a link ie \\fwdata\DATA\WebDocs\

Comment: @snj013 `I am not able to change the text column in the db` why not? I wouldn't imagine this column is used by a foreign key or has an index of some sort.

Comment: It is very confusing when a column named `DocumentName` stores document contents. In order to store arbitrary files in there, such as xls, you would need to pass a `varbinary(max)` parameter to the query and then do `cast(cast(@val as varchar(max)) as text)` on the server side, but to tell you the truth, I do not know if that will preserve all bytes in all cases. You are not supposed to store arbitrary binary streams in `text`. There is `varbinary(max)` for that, and if you absolutely have to use obsolete data types, then it's `image`.